# Unity. Создание объектов внутри Canvas через скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня на сцене есть `Canvas`. Все объекты располагаются внутри (кнопки, надписи, картинки). Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку(`UI.Button`) внутри `Canvas` создавались объекты на основе созданного `Prefab'a`.

Искал много разных способов, пока работающий не нашел. Объекты создаются, но вне `Canvas'а` и, естественно, не в тех координатах, которые мне необходимы.

Это в скрипте кнопки:

```
public GameObject Canvas; //Основной Canvas
public UnityEngine.GameObject objectPrefab// Создаваемый объект;
public void Clicked() //Метод назначенный на нажатие
{
    FireManPrefab.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform);//По документации, я так понял должно назначать объект в котором будет находится этот объект
    Instantiate(FireManPrefab);//Создание объекта
}
```

Это в скрипте Prefab'a:

```
void Start () 
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(50.0f, -50.0f);//Назначение расположение, мне необходимы эти координаты внутри Canvas.                 
}
```

Comment: пробуй так: var x =  Instantiate(FireManPrefab);    x.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform);

Comment: почти угадал с порядком действий)) Но, как написал выше Valera Kvip - надо **в начале** инстанциировать объект, получив на него ссылку, а потом уже к нему применять `SetParent`, а не наоборот))

Comment: @forge456 всё зависит...... если одноразовая операция, то достаточно `var`, если собираешься где-то еще им манипулировать, то такого же типа (FireManPrefab) или GameObject (тоже зависит...)) )

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я уже попробовал  `GameObject `, вроде работает, но при этом координаты не x 50 y -50, а около 600-700

Comment: @forge456 вообще, как правило, у префабов ставят позицию `0,0,0`. Чтоб его не потерять, не искать чёрт знает где и пр. Однако если тебе надо создать объект в определенных координатах, то у метода **[Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)** есть перегрузки на этот случай.... где одним из параметров можно указать позицию `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);` .......кстати.. на сколько я понял, там даже есть перегрузка, которая позволяет сразу впихнуть в родителя

Comment: Ааа. с родителем перегрузка для версии >= 5.4

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в общем проблема была в том, что координаты для объекта, которые я задавал через `gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2();` считались от нижнего левого угла канваса, а канвас начинался от координат 0, 0 и уходил вниз. Мне нужно было расположить объект в самом верху по центру. Я использовал `Screen.Width / 2 и Screen.Height`

Answer (score 4):

A - любая переменная

B - Прифаб

С - Твой Canvas

```
GameObject A = Instantiate(B, B.transform.position = new Vector3(куда тебе надо), 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    А.transform.SetParent(С.transform, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public GameObject Canvas; //Основной Canvas
public UnityEngine.GameObject objectPrefab// Создаваемый объект;
public void Clicked() //Метод назначенный на нажатие
{
int index = 0; //от 0 до максимального размера иерархии
GameObject _delta = Instantiate(FireManPrefab) as GameObject;
_delta.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, false);
_delta.transform.SetSiblingIndex(index); //SetAsLastSibling() для того чтобы сделать объект "ближним" в иерархии или SetAsFirstSibling() наоборот. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все куда проще:

```
Public GameObject Префаб;
//Ссылка на канвас или на объект в который вы хотите создать дочерний объект
Public Transform Канвас; 

Instantiate(Префаб,Канвас.transform);
```